# Optimization Expectations in the STL

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, stl

I'm curious as to how much optimization the compiler will do, so...

```
// assume we have this declared somewhere
std::vector<int> vec;

// my question is, when fully optimized will this...
for (int i(0); i<100; ++i)
    vec.push_back(i);

// evaluate to this? psuedo code...
const size_t size = size();
const size_t newsize = size + 100;
if (size < vec.capacity())
    vec.exponentialGrowth();
vec.setSize(newsize);
for (size_t i(size); i<newsize; ++i)
    vector[i] = i;
```

I'm working with Visual Studio Express 2012 with optimization enabled.
I've tried looking at the disassembly but the optimization makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Re: "I've tried looking at the disassembly but the optimization makes it difficult to read." That probably means the optimizer is doing a good job of optimizing. :-P On a more serious note, I don't think the code you present will be optimized away like that, unless the state of the art of optimizers have approached magical levels of optimization recently.

Comment: Probably not. If you know the target size, use `resize` (or `reserve`). At the same time, be aware that the average number of copies done approaches an upper limit (around 3 with most implementations, if memory serves) so even at worst, it's rarely as big an issue as many people initially think.

Comment: Instead of using int as the template argument, use a user defined class. Instrument the different constructors and see what happens.

Comment: @In silico. i'm aware generally "optimization therefor obfuscation" but its silly to assume "obfuscation therefore optimization". I don't think it is magical, it's just moving the capcity check outside the loop right?

Comment: @user515430, "instrument the different constructors", please explain this statement briefly.

Comment: @Histuries. Put print statments in the constructors (default, copy, move) as well as copy assignment and move assignment. See how often the different functions are called.

Comment: What is it that you would like optimized? Where is the cost that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @Histuries: It was a joke. Hence, the :-P emoticon. The reason why this would require what I consider to be "magical" levels of optimization is because in order for the optimizer to do what you present it requires that the compiler have some kind of deep understanding of how `push_back` works, which it certainly doesn't. It's dead obvious to humans, but remember computers can't operate at quite the same level of abstraction and thinking as a human does.

Comment: An optimizer does not understand the intent of a program.  It would never convert one function call to another, or add a function call.

Comment: @Insilico ... I had thought that the compiler would perform an optimization across function calls and was likely to find the redundancies. I understand now the level of abstraction referenced here. I don't see it getting optimized in this way, and that WOULD be pretty magical.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Nothing highly specific thought this is a relevant case. I guess the insert() function is designed for this instance, but my question was more largely related to what i expected my compiler to optimize and what not.

Comment: @Histuries: The problem I see is that there are multiple levels to the question. The *compiler* will not be able to optimize algorithms, but the standard library implementation might have special cases to handle some situations. It is hard to come up with a list of what can/cannot be *optimized* in the general sense as these two get combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the assembly generated by VS 2012 with the `/Ox` option specified, the compiler doesn't optimize to reserve capacity for all 100 elements in one shot.

It adds elements one-by-one, growing the capacity of the vector by 50% when additional room is needed.  The capacity of the vector starts at 0, then grows like so:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19, 28, 42, 63, 94, 141
```

GCC 4.7.2 with `-O2` behaves similarly, but grows by doubling capacity instead of growing by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector` will resize exponentially, whether compiler optimizations are turned-on or not.

If you are worried about resize performance (and can't `reserve` enough space in advance), consider using `std::deque`. To quote [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm): *"A deque is easier to use, and inherently more efficient for growth, than a vector."*

Comment: I had exponentialGrowth() in the code becase I assume reserve will allocate only what is asked for while if the optimization simply moved the resize check out of the loop it would almost certainly have grown exponentially. This doesn't account for situations where exponential growth wouldn't grow enough but ultimately the question is about optimization expectations.

Comment: @Histuries The `push_back` will grow the `vector` exponentially and I doubt the compiler is smart enough to understand the connection between the number of `push_back` calls and the ultimate memory needed. That's a guess, but an educated one: compiler simply doesn't operate at that level of abstraction. It's easy to check, after all: just read the `capacity` with and without optimizations turned-on and if there is a difference, I'm wrong.